# How to put key/values into a HashMap from StringBuilder using loop? - Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm using several techniques here, so it's hard to find help online.
I need to populate a `HashMap<String, String>` with values I take from part of a `StringBuilder`, then take the keys and add them into an `ArrayList<String>`, then print the list. But when I print, I get a list full of `nulls`. I don't know why, I thought it would print the values I got from the `StringBuilder`. It should print:  `Values taken from the hashmap keys: ABCDEFGHI`. (The reason I used `StringBuilder` is because `String` is immutable, is this correct thinking too?)

Also, I figured using a loop to print the list is okay, since my keys are actually numbers.

I've never created a HashMap before, so maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for your help.

**Here is my code:**

```
    // create HashMap from String
    StringBuilder alphaNum = new StringBuilder("1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I");

    Map<String, String> myAlphaNum = new HashMap<String, String>(9);

    // for loop puts key and values in map, taken from String
    for (int i = 0; i < alphaNum.length();)
    {
        myAlphaNum.put(alphaNum.substring(i, ++i), alphaNum.substring(i, ++i));
    }
    if (myAlphaNum.containsKey(1))
        System.out.println("Key is there.");
    else
        System.out.println("Key is null.");

    // create ArrayList, add values to it using map keys
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // for loop gets the "number" keys from HashMap to get the "letter" values
    for (int j = 1; j <= myAlphaNum.size(); j++)
        arrayList.add(myAlphaNum.get(j));


    System.out.print("Values taken from the hashmap keys: ");
    for (String list : arrayList)
        System.out.print(list);
```

**Console:**

```
Key is null.

Values taken from the hashmap keys: nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

Comment: `arrayList.add(myAlphaNum.get(j));` but you defined `Map<String, String> myAlphaNum` so how would you expect your map to find the value of a String key providing an Integer one? Use a `Map<Integer, String>` then with `Integer.parseInt` instead.

Comment: Thank you ZouZou!! I can't believe it was so easy. I started out using Integer, but then had troubles using conversions, kept getting errors. That makes so much sense though about the Map not taking a String. I guess I assumed it would take any key, but that's is wrong. If you write this as an answer, I will give you the green checkmark, since you were 1st. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using containsKey/get with an Integer as parameter, while your map keys are defined as String. That's why you got null.

I would recommend to use a `Map<Integer, String> myAlphaNum = new HashMap<Integer, String>(9);` and in your loop `myAlphaNum.put(Integer.parseInt(alphaNum.substring(i, ++i)), alphaNum.substring(i, ++i));`. Then you'll get your desired output.

Also you could the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a `Collection` as parameter (or just sysout `myAlphaNum.values()`) directly.

```
// create ArrayList, add values to it using map keys
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(myAlphaNum.values());
System.out.println(arrayList); //[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]
```

Comment: Thanks again ZouZou! I really like your ArrayList suggestions too. Much more concise. +1!

Comment: @NoniA. Cool it worked! Don't hesitate to read the doc of the classes you are using, you'll find that there is often a method that does what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: I do read them a ton, but sometimes things fall through the cracks. ;) Going to be more thorough next time!

Answer (score 1):

`myAlphaNum` has keys of type String, so passing an int to `get` (`myAlphaNum.get(j)`) will always return null.

There are several ways to iterate over the values (or keys or entries) of the map.

For example (assuming you only care about the values) :

```
for (String value : myAlphaNum.values())
    arrayList.add(value);
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, this code looks much nicer than mine. :) But what is the `.values`, is that a known method used for a HashMap object? It says `returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map.` But I didn't know what they meant by "view".

Comment: @NoniA. `values()` returns a Collection of all the values in the Map. There's also a `keySet()` method that returns all the keys, and a `entrySet()` method that returns all the entries (i.e. key+value).

Comment: Nice! That sounds so much easier than a clunky traditional for loop. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 // create HashMap from String
        StringBuilder alphaNum = new StringBuilder("1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I");

        Map<String, String> myAlphaNum = new HashMap<String, String>(9);

        // for loop puts key and values in map, taken from String
        for (int i = 0; i < alphaNum.length();)
        {
            myAlphaNum.put(alphaNum.substring(i, ++i), alphaNum.substring(i, ++i));
        }

        System.out.println(myAlphaNum);
        if (myAlphaNum.containsKey(1))
            System.out.println("Key is there.");
        else
            System.out.println("Key is null.");

        // create ArrayList, add values to it using map keys
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // for loop gets the "number" keys from HashMap to get the "letter" values
        for (int j = 1; j <= myAlphaNum.size(); j++)
            arrayList.add(myAlphaNum.get(j+""));


        System.out.print("Values taken from the hashmap keys: ");
        for (String list : arrayList)
            System.out.print(list);
```

You can try the above code. You have used string key bit while retriving Integer so it wont return anything.